# Promise not resolved

Tags: javascript, promise, axios, es6-promise

I need the result of this axios call. I have tried many ways but I can´t get the promise resolved. I am allways getting promise pending with status resolved and [[PromiseValues]] This is the last one I have tried:

```
function getResult() {
  let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve(axios.get(URL))
  });

  return promise;
};

let theResult = getResult().then(function(result) {
  return result.data
});
```

Comment: `axios.get(URL)` - is a promise already. Do `axios.get(URL).then(result => result.data);`

Comment: It returns 

Promise {<pending>}
__proto__: Promise
[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"
[[PromiseValue]]: Array(9)

I don´t know how to acces the values

Comment: @LadyCrispy that's because you are trying to `console.log` it before it's done.

Comment: How can I use theResult instead? Because when I try to use it, it say it's undefined

Comment: This is starting to look like a dup of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

`axios.get` - a method that returns a Promise.

Either

`axios.get(URL).then(result => result.data);`

or

```
function getResult(url) {
  return axios.get(url);
};

let theResult = getResult('<URL goes here>').then(function(result) {
  return result.data
});
```

Comment: I think the issue is that the OP is somehow expecting `theResult` to be their value, but it's still a promise (as it should be).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot expect return value from promise by doing `var data = getResult(url);`. **data** will have **promise object** which has its **status and value(if resolved or rejected).**

```
function getResult() {
    let promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        resolve(axios.get("https://api.github.com/users/mralexgray/repos"))
    });

    return promise; 
};

getResult().then((result) => {

    let theResult = result.data;

    /** process result **/


}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err, "error");
})
```

You are resolving your `promise` to another promise `axios.get(URL)`, because of that you are getting `pending` as a status even after calling `resolve`. Try to resolve it with any other value(non-promise) you will get resolved status.

I would recommend you to go through [article.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)